# Running a jar which contain the junit

Tags: java, eclipse, junit, jar

I compiled a java project which contains implementation as well as junit . I work fine in eclipse. But After converting to jar and Run in Linux terminal it is showing some Exceptions.

I have done the implementation in main class and excecuting the test class by  junit.textui.testrunner.run (xyz.class) command

I am getting the exception on running the jar in linux console as **NoClassDefFoundError for junit/framework/testcase.**

On commenting the junit.textui.testrunner.run (xyz.class) and create a jar of same implementation ,it works fine in console

Comment: your jar has dependency on junit.jar to you need to include it in the classpath

Answer (score 1):

The jar you created has dependency on junit.jar so download it from [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjunit38jar.htm)
and include it in the classpath while running your jar
One more thing as you are using terminal to run the jar

**A small note** - When you use -jar option, the JAR file is the source of all user classes, and other user class path settings are ignored. That means you cannot use -cp with -jar